# Troubleshooting AT&T Arris BGW210-700 gateway

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing, wireless-router

I've read most of the other posts and numerous forum threads on this gateway and its associated issues, but while troubleshooting my in-law's network I've come across something that quite intrigued me.

First of all, the wifi broadcast started displaying behavior of intermittently dropping connection (inferred from viewing `ping` with `-t` switch).  This has been going on for a while, and now it's completely down.  So far, pretty straightforward.  Now, here's the strange part: apparently, the head of household here had an alternate network running this whole time.  I'd been aware of it, but didn't want to stick my nose in where I had no business doing so, so I'd never questioned the network topography before now.  Come to find out, that SSID broadcast was functioning properly, albeit with higher latency, but no drops at all.  I get the credentials to login during my attempt to troubleshoot, but I'm taken aback when I find it's the **same as the one I'm troubleshooting**.  So I log in and check the gateway, and lo and behold, **it *is* the same gateway**.  I'm not experienced with multi-router setups, but I did check `arp -a` (saw no indication of another router), and I also tried `tracert` to `8.8.8.8` and there's only one hop between gateway to ISP's server, so I *believe* that should imply the SSID's are being broadcasted from the same router??  So here are my points of confusion:

- If **both** SSID's are being broadcasted from the same gateway device, why would one broadcast be working while the other is down?
- Or, if they are **not** from the same equipment, how can I confirm or rule this out?
- In **either case**, since one SSID broadcast is actually working and it's behind the same gateway topographically speaking, am I correct in inferring this rules out the ONT box/cabling/infrastructure as the root cause?